Deciphering words in reports from canonical visitations (1618–1748)
This is a continuation of my attempts to better understand the history of the town in which I live (see e.g., here) - I currently try to decipher all detailed reports from canonical visitations of my home village which took place in 17th and 18th c. Most of these texts are clear to me, but in some cases the handwriting is very poor.. Therefore I ask for help:)
This time I worked hard with https://www.vocabula.lat/, which allows the user to search using wildcard characters (actually, using simple regular expressions).
I've also built a corpus of similar documents, to see whether a word I deciphered actually appeared in such texts - large collections of them can be found e.g. in:

"Monumenta Historica Dioeceseos Wladislaviensis" series
"Acta visitationum dioecesis samogitiae (A. D. 1611–1651)"
"Akta wizytacji podkrakowskiej parafii Zielonki z XVI-XVII wieku w zasobie Archiwum Kurii Metropolitalnej w Krakowie"
"Materiały źródłowe do dziejów Kościoła w obecnej diecezji katowickiej – Protokoły wizytacyjne z ..." (e.g., "z 1619 r.", "z 1665 r.", "z 1720 i 1721 r.")

However, in some cases even this did not help, especially when a word was very abbreviated...
Below is a list of words/phrases with which I struggle along with an image showing where they appear in the text (I'll update this list as answers/suggestions will start to appear, so that it will be clear which riddles were not yet solved).
In each section there are also links to full scans of the respective page(s).
Any help will be appreciated! :)

AV 23 (AD 1730)

pp. 866-867-868-869
1) What day is it? 19? 
2) I could not find what is "braxatorium [= brewery] cum olla". Any ideas? 
3) What number is it? 70? 
4) Is it "Fiasowka"? (see also AV Cap 61, no. 1) 
5) Is it "ossorium ab-alius"? (see also AV Cap 61, no. 3) 
AV Cap 61 (AD 1730)

pp. 846-847-848-849
1) Is it "Fasovka"? (see also AV 23, no. 4) 
2) What does this "-tt" suffix stands for? 
3) Is it "ossorium ab-altius" (see also AV 23, no. 5) In this document I often saw prepositions being "glued" to the succeeding word (e.g.: a-fluvio, a-rivo, in-fundo, a-tergo etc.). 
AV 33 (AD 1748)

pp. 81-82-83-84-85-86-87-88-89
1) Is it "[pri]ma"? 
2) Is it "lebaculam"? In a similar document I found a word "lebetem". 
3) Is is "de authentico tamen non co[nte]stat"? 
4) ? 
5) Is it "similiter" (somehow abbreviated)? 
AV Cap 46 (AD 1655)

pp. 38-39-40-41-42
1) It is some number ("Crux ... valoris # marc[arum].") 
2) Is it "octo"? 
3) Is it "cum columna spa[dici]bus distincta"? 
4) Is it "sub custodia d[e]nario[s] claviu[m] p[ro] victricos"? 
5) Is it a symbol for "florens" (currency)? 
6) Something "pro def#tione" (I could not find any word which would pass here). 
7) I suppose it is some abbreviation... 
8) Could this be related to "Myślenice", a town nearby? (I think in some other documents I saw a similar spelling of that name) 
9) Is it "pr[ou]t"? 
10) Is it "t[i]t[ulu]m"? 
11) I found the word "cxterx" in a few texts, but I have no idea what does it mean. 
12) "con clado"? 
13) Is it "ministerium anim[arum]"? 
AV Cap 47 (AD 1665)



pp. 406-407-408-409-410-411-412-413
1) Is it "Imago Crucifixi D[omi]ni N[ostri] V[iro] sculpta"? 
2) ? 
3) Is it something related to "sim[i]l[ite]r"? 
4) ? 
5) What number it it? 
6) Is it "Tobalia duo maiora praetiosa."? 
7) Is it "In eo hospitali manent pauperes nonem, qui piorum eleemosinis sustentantur miseri satis et egentes.? 
8) "nil"? 
9) Is it "Ob absentiam visit[ati]o[n]is tempore R. Parochi nil /ink/ ea nobis constare potuit prout et in alijs plene informari non potuimus abinde."? 
10) Is it "de provisione ecclesiasticae"? 
11) Is it "ex quibus numerus animarum ad curam Parochi spectantium et pro Paschate com[muni]canti[um] ascendit ad quatuor millia et ultra."? 
X) What number is it? 
12) ? 
13) ? 
14) ? (this word also appears on p. 412) 
15) ? (this word also appears on p. 412) 
16) ? ("quam quod praeseru#? e[st] Const[itutionibus Provincialibus") 
17) ? ("ad i#{bus/tius}? floreni") 
18) What number is it? 
19) Is it "nec quod quam in praemissis ub[eri]us parochiani graventur"? 
20) Is it "per Illu[strissi]mu[m] D[ominum] Loci Ordinariu[m] i[nte]rrogan[tur]"? 
21) Is it just "restitu[er]etur"? If so, then why is there a tilde above? 
22) Is it "simil[ite]r"? 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27) Is it "Cum vitricis aequo unam clavem ipse aliam vitrici habeant legata a fidelibus pro eccl[esi]a in usus suos non convertat per hoc animi graventur cum scientia sua et ad restitu[ti]o[n]em inique acceptorum obligatur et fideles ab arefaciendo eccl[esi]ae videntes viam in dispersione[m] et usus privatos transire legata sua deterrentur et scandalizantur."? 
28) ? 
29) ? 
30) Is it " et in posterum de provisione Parochi dicti famuli Eccl[esi]ae salarientur"? 
31) ? 
32) Is it "Corporalia et purificatoria ad minus 6 munda et nova comparentur."? 
33) ? ("Novi cassulae usuales et aliae eccl[esi]ae supellex dictae reficiatur attrita et la#.") 
34) ? ("R. Parochus penes eccl[esi]a[m] spensum suum saepius resident et bonum ordinem in[scripti]o[ni]bus? servare studeat.") 
35, 36) ? ("In reliquo noverit se vocatur #d..veiuq[ue]? pastore Chr[ist]o Jesu ad procurandum salutem animarum suorum parochianorum dignnum seigitur hocce in agone atletum exhibeat bravium immortalitatis ab eide[m] suo te[m]pore latur[am]? et gloria[m].") 

Perhaps the mods will have more feedback, but I think the question (as currently posed) doesn't fit the scope of a simple Q&A: It's an entire project. Perhaps you can find a way to split this into smaller components?

You're right, because... this is actually the page I've created and I'm constantly actively developing ;)
So on that page you only see my guessing (and it's sort of alpha version, with many errors e.g. when it comes to word endings).
